# Get the TextField value of a custom view from a main view using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Im trying to access the @State text of a TextField from a main view. I created a custom TextField, and implemented inside a login view(main view), and I need to get the text of the TextField, but I have no access to the TextFied itself from the mais view. Is there a way to pass that value through the views? What I mean is, get the *textFieldContent* and pass it to the login view to be used inside the view model.

**Login View**

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @StateObject private var loginVM = LoginViewModel()
    
    
    //MARK: - Main text field
    @State var email: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                Spacer(minLength: 30)
                Section{
                    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 24) {
                        InsetMainTextField(textFieldName: "Email", textFieldPlaceholder: "email@email.com")
                        
                        InsetMainTextField(textFieldName: "Password", textFieldPlaceholder: "Enter your password")
                        
                    ...

                    }// VStack
                }// Section 
            }// ScrollView
        }// NavigationView
    }
}
```

**Custom TextField View**

```
struct InsetMainTextField: View{
    
    ...
    
    @State var textFieldContent: String = ""
    @State var isFocused: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            Text(textFieldName)
                .font(.headline)
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                .frame(height: 70)
                .foregroundColor(.clear)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 2)
                        .overlay(
                            TextField(textFieldPlaceholder, text: $textFieldContent)
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                                .frame(height: 70)
                        )
                )
        }// VStack
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into @Binding

Comment: Agree with the above. State should be owned by a parent and passed down to the children via Binding -- don't try to reach down into child views from higher levels.

Comment: It worked when using Binding! Thank you very much.

Comment: @VinniciusPereira can you post final result, pls?